# Intellij Idea Structural Replacement (replacing autowired annotation)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I wonder whether it's possible to replace all the Autowired fields with final ones and @RequiredArgsConstructor below the class declaration?

For instance, replace the following code

```
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Reposiroty repository;

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

...

}
```

with something like that:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    private final Reposiroty repository;


    private final Service service;

...

}
```

Thanks in advance!